# Proof related to circumcircle of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a triangle $ABC$ with incenter $I$. $AI$ extended meets the circumcircle of $ABC$ at $M$. Prove that $CM=BM=IM$.

I was able to prove that $CM=BM$ taking advantage of the fact that the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ also meets at $M$, but I don't see how to get the $IM$ part. Can anyone help? :)

Comment: You can get that $CM=BM$ more easily by observing that they are chords subtended by congruent angles (namely, the bisected halves of $\angle A$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
C \hat AI =B \hat AM = B \hat CM \\
M \hat IC = I \hat AC + I \hat CA \\
M \hat CI = B \hat AM + I \hat CB
$$
since we also have 
$$
I \hat CA = I \hat CB
$$
the triangle $MCI$ is isosceles

Answer (score 0):

I think you could work this out using vectors with the following steps:

1) Determine the line L intersecting A and I.

2) Use the midpoints of the triangle sides to determine the circumcenter S (See 'http://www.mathopenref.com/trianglecircumcenter.html').

3) Determine the radius R of the circumcenter circle C to produce a formula for C.

4) Determine the intersection of circle C with line L. One point will be the triangle vertex A while the other will be point M (See 'http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html').

5) Determine the distance between I and M using a distance function d. You are likely just going to use d((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2) .

6) Verify whether or not d(I,M) == d(B,M) == d(C,I) .